# How Can I Make My Discord Bot to Handle a LOT OF MESSAGES/COMMANDS In the Same Time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Long story short, I developed a simple discord bot using discod.js.
At the beginning I run it on a my private server for testing purposes and debugging.
It went fine because I'm the only one on the server.
But!
when I test on my friends server, it was crashing a lot.
For example, when we want to play music, if I type "!play" and in the same time my friend gives another command, the bot will crash...
How can I make my bot executing one command at a time and handle a lot of commands together?
Help will be appreciated. Thanks!
EDIT: There is a way of not using cooldown? I'm thinking about a way of taking the commands and put them in a queue and then execute each one from the queue.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. Do you have any code examples for your specific case?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.